# Show all data stored in Table1 and the last record in Table2 related to Table1

Tags: mysql

I have a Database, my query is related to 2 tables (ms_recepciones & ms_estados). This database is to Manage a Mobile Repair Store.

[Tabla > ms_recepciones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSPjS.png)

[Tabla > ms_estados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsg0U.png)

---

A record in ms_recepciones, may have different states. These states are stored in a history in ms_estados. For example: admitted, budgeted, invoiced, canceled...

They are related by the key id_recepcion

[?] My question is:

I need to display all the data of the ms_recepciones and the status has to be only the last registered in ms_estados.

For example:

If the id_recepcion #50 of ms_recepciones has had the states -> admitted, delivered, invoiced. It will show only invoiced (because it's the last.).

The same with all the other receptions to be shown in a single table together.

Later I hope to filter: current state -> invoiced, admitted, etc.

In advance, thank you very much for your help. 4 people we tried to do it, without success.

```
SELECT 
   r.id_recepcion, coalesce(max(e.fecha_estado), '0000-00-00 00:00:00') as UltFecha, e.id_estado, e.estado
FROM 
   ms_estados e
INNER JOIN
   ms_recepciones r
ON
   r.id_recepcion = e.id_recepcion
GROUP BY 
   e.id_recepcion
```

This code I tried, but the first row is incorrect.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `COALESCE` clause will give you the latest date, but `e.id_estado` and `e.estado` will not necessarily give you the matching columns to that latest row.

You are not the first person to have this issue. See the answers to this question: [Optimize sub-query selecting last record of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156163/optimize-sub-query-selecting-last-record-of-each-group).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check the link you provided. I will also try another type of query. Maybe COALESCE is not suitable for this case.

Comment: ``COALESCE`` is not the problem. The problem is that there will be no correlation between the row returned by ``max(e.fecha_estado)`` and the row returned by ``e.id_estado, e.estado``.