# SQL Select Unique Entires

Tags: mysql

I have in my table:

```
ID Name   Age
1  James  15
2  James  16
3  Joseph 16
4  Joseph 18
5  Steve  4
```

and I want to return:

```
5 Steve 4
1 James 15
3 Joseph 16
```

ie. Unique entries based on the Name row (choose the one with lowest ID when there are multiple of the same Name), and ordered by Age

What would be the correct SQL statement?

I have:

```
Select * FROM table Where True GROUP BY Name ORDER BY Age
```

It seems to be returning a lot of unique results, but it's too slow (table has >250,000 entries and it takes >30seconds to process), I wonder if there is a faster way to do this?

Comment: Actually...the query I had, the result is actually not correct. The result is missing a lot of rows (regardless unique or not) from the query without the "GROUP BY Name" part...not sure why..

Comment: By the way, what result do you expect having `1 John 5`, `2 John 5`? :)

Comment: Oh nevermind, I misunderstood what you seek for.

Answer (score 0):

try this

> SELECT *
>     FROM table
>     WHERE ID in (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM table group by name)
>     ORDER by age

You just group the datasets by name and get `MIN(ID)` and use this as 'where' condition for your selection

Answer (score 0):

Another way of querying this, usually better where performance is needed, provided you have (and that's NOT an option here) an INDEX on `Name`:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND t2.ID < t1.ID
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL;
```

A quick [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131237/mysql-can-i-do-a-left-join-and-pull-only-one-row-from-the-join-table/11134161#11134161).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to select based on the minimum `ID`, which is a unique field, you just need to get the minimum `ID`s per name first, then join those `ID`s to the main table. This will be much faster than using a subquery in a `WHERE` as the subselect of the minimums gets executed just one time, whereas a subquery would execute for each row in the main table (250,000+ times!).

```
SELECT
    b.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT MIN(ID) AS minID
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY Name
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    tbl b ON a.minID = b.ID
ORDER BY
    b.Age
```