# MySql select statement get most recent row for each client_id

Tags: mysql, database, select

Hi i have an issue with a mysql select statement i cant get my head around,

Table client_directory_data

id int,
verified int,
client_id int,
created timestamp,
description longtext

select * from client_directory_data where verified = 1 order by created desc

but this selects multiple rows for each client_id

what i need to do is to select every client_id which has a verified = 1 but only get the most recent row for each client_id, i hope that makes sense.

Comment: not sure what happened here on this page but someone had actually answered it correctly with the link to the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cc95/1

Comment: whoever it was deserves the tick as a correct answer cause it works, select * 
from client_directory_data
where verified = 1
group by client_id
having max(created)

Comment: This sqlfiddle is **wrong**: ID for client_id = 1 should be 2, not 1...

Comment: Try the same sqlfiddle with my query ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That makes sense and is a classic question.

Assuming that `the most recent row is the one with highest id`, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM client_directory_data c
LEFT JOIN client_directory_data d ON c.client_id = d.client_id AND d.verified = 1 AND d.id > c.id
WHERE d.id IS NULL
    AND c.verified = 1;
```

You can have an explanation of this query pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131237/mysql-can-i-do-a-left-join-and-pull-only-one-row-from-the-join-table/11134161#11134161).

Comment: thanks Olivier but this is only pulling a single client_id and there are lots of client_id rows, any other ideas please

Comment: I'm really positive this pattern is working. Are you really sure you tested it on a dataset with multiple client_id values with correspondant verified = 1 ?

Comment: Try my query on the sqlfiddle given in your question's comment, do you still have only 1 row ?

Comment: Surely you could change d.id > c.id to d.created > c.created to remove the ID assumption? Also, I think you need d.verified = 1 in the ON clause, otherwise it will only return client_id for which the last entry was verified

Comment: @Braiba You are 100% right about both comments and that earns you a +1 :)

Comment: @cghrmauritius It was due to my forgetting the `AND d.verified = 1` in the ON clause, as cghrmauritius kindly remarked.

Comment: how do i accept both your answers as both are correct who wants the credit here

Comment: I was benchmarking this just as a comparison against my method, purely out of my own interest (see my edited answer), but it seems this approach has some serious issues for anything above fairly smallish tables. The is that this way MySQL has to actually make all the joins before it can do the where clause, the data involved in which grows exponentially with the table size. I actually went back to the third query I was using for benchmarking and just left it running to see how long it would take - so far it's been 3 hours without finishing, and this is on an 8 core server with 15gig of RAM.

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue I face all the time. Fortunately there's a nice little trick for doing this:

```
SELECT
client_id,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY created DESC),",",1) AS `id`
FROM client_directory_data
WHERE verified = 1
GROUP BY client_id
```

And if you want the whole row you can just join onto it like so:

```
SELECT
*
FROM (
  SELECT
  client_id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY created DESC),",",1) AS `id`
  FROM client_directory_data
  WHERE verified = 1
  GROUP BY client_id
) ids
JOIN client_directory_data USING (id);
```

Of course if you're ordering by an indexed field anyway (that you could therefore join on efficiently anyway), it's better to use `MAX(id) AS id`, although it actually has very little impact on performance. The main reason to use MAX() is really to make the code a little simpler. It also avoids the pitfalls you may encounter if the field contains commas (which you can get around with a different seperator for the group concat) or hitting the max GROUP_CONCAT length (which can be extended with `SET group_concat_max_len = xxx;` and only causes warnings anyway).

I can see why this would intuitively seem like it would have performance issues, however it's actually the best performng method I've found for these queries - especially on large tables.

Here are some benchmarks I've taken from some of the larger tables currently available to me comparing the three methods in this thread.

Query A: (~5,000 records, ~900 results, non-indexed field)

- GROUP_CONCAT method: 0.0100 seconds
- MAX method: 0.102 seconds
- LEFT JOIN method: 0.0082 seconds

Query B : (~300,000 records, ~95,000 results)

- GROUP_CONCAT method: 1.8618 seconds
- MAX method: 1.7904 seconds
- LEFT JOIN method: 6.4649 seconds

Query C : (~300,000 records, ~7 results)

- GROUP_CONCAT method: 0.103 seconds
- MAX method: 0.0102 seconds
- LEFT JOIN method: (I got bored after 4 hours)

Query D : (~500,000 records, ~5,000 different values of the field being grouped)

- GROUP method: 0.1355 seconds
- MAX Method : 0.0429 seconds
- LEFT JOIN method: (I got bored after 10 minutes)

Comment: Nice trick, but only gives the id, not the whole row. At this point, writing `SELECT client_id, MAX(id) FROM client_directory_data WHERE verified = 1 GROUP BY client_id;` is stricly the same.

Comment: Only if the row with the MAX id is the same row as the MAX created, which it *probably* is, but it depends on the system. Once you have the row it's easy enough to join onto it, but I suppose I should probably actually include that in my answer. *edits*...

Comment: This is a good answer but I'll go on fighting for my bone saying that my query is really better where performance is needed as it doesn't involve a subquery.

Comment: I actually used to do it your way, but when I did a load of benchmark tests while I was working with a ~1million record table this way came out better. It probably depends on the kind of data you're storing, but in my experience the subquery joining onto a primary key is actually a lot more efficient than joining a table to itself like that. I'd be interested to hear which works out best for the OP though.

Comment: Using `GROUP_CONCAT()` for this kind of queries ("greatest-n-per-group") is not good, for various reasons. Not because of the subquery.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I'm aware of the issues that you can get with commas in data and exceeding the group_concat length, both of which are fairly trivial to work around, but I've not found any other reasons not to use this method and I've used it a lot.

Comment: I forgot to mark that comment as @ypercube (I've not use SO enough to know if that affects who gets notifications about comments, but it seems to), but I'd be really interested in a response. I'm always looking for ways I can improve my MySQL queries.

Comment: You are joining on a column that is created with `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. This cannot be faster than a join on an existing column. There are several ways to have such a query, search the [`greatest-n-per-group`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql) tag and test performance in a database of yours.

Comment: Additionally `GROUP_CONCAT()` will be problematic when there are too many items concatenated and the length of the produced string is too big. (you have to carefully define the related setting in MySQL settings): [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)

Comment: @Braiba: Just read the part you are saying that you are familiar with the setings and the workarounds. So, my answer should be: performance. It may get unnoticed with small tables but with medium to big, it will be real slow.

Comment: @ypercube I can see why intuitively this may seem like the case, but in reality it's *really* not, in fact the other method in this thread suffers massively from large data sets, whereas this method barely flinches. I've edited some benchmark tests I did into my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Make id as primary key for the table client_directory_data