# Mysql FULLTEXT search with GROUP BY, keep row value that has the highest score

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, inner-join, full-text-search

In two FULLTEXT searches, I look for the search terms in the title of the book and the tags and get the following result:

```
rScore                  tScore                  ID
...
1.235689725827653       0                       406
0.928482055664062       2.37063312530518        406
0.928482055664062       0                       406
0.453363467548853       0                       520
...
```

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE, all duplicate ID have been concatenated taking highest scores:**

```
rScore                  tScore                  ID
...
1.235689725827653       2.37063312530518        406
0.453363467548853       0                       520
...
```

, but after a GROUP BY, ID 406 was grouped in this row column:

```
...
MATCH_SCORE_TITLE       MATCH_SCORE_TAGS        ID
0.928482055664062       0                       406
0.453363467548853       0                       520
...
```

How can I group all these results and keeping the max value of each MATCH? I know this has been asked before and can be done with a JOIN, but I didn't find it with a combination of two rows, plus I already have JOINS in my query since TITLE and TAGS are in two different tables.

**UPDATE:**
I have 3 tables, "registrants" (the left table with the titles to search), the "registrants_tags" (relational table between the left and the right table) and "tags" (the right table with the tags to search. Here is a simplified version of the SQL query:

```
SELECT
 tags.tag,    (Also tried (GROUP_CONCAT(`tags`.`tag`) AS tags)
 MAX(MATCH(registrants.story_title) AGAINST('bob')) as rScore,
 MAX(MATCH(tags.tag) AGAINST('bob')) as tScore,
 registrants.id, registrants.story_title
FROM registrants 
LEFT JOIN registrants_tags ON registrants.id = registrants_tags.registrant 
LEFT JOIN tags ON registrants_tags.tag = tags.id
WHERE MATCH(registrants.story_title) AGAINST('bob')
 OR MATCH(tags.tag) AGAINST('bob')
GROUP BY registrants.id
ORDER BY (rScore + tScore) DESC
```

Which gives me error message: "#1247 - Reference 'tscore' not supported (reference to group function)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort by the score, and use a `max` on a subquery to get the final preferred row.

For example:

```
SELECT  id, story_title,
    max(match_score_title) as titleScore,
    max(match_score_tags) as as tagScore
FROM (
    SELECT
        MATCH(registrants.story_title) AGAINST('bob') as rScore,
        MATCH(tags.tag) AGAINST('bob') as tScore,
        registrants.id, registrants.story_title
    FROM
    registrants 
    LEFT JOIN registrant_tags on registrant_tags.registrant=registrant.id
    LEFT JOIN tags on tags.id=registrant_tags.tag
    WHERE rScore > 0 or tScore > 0
) AS score_matcher
group by ID
ORDER BY (rScore + tScore) DESC
```

That ought to work for you.  It may not be the quickest query in the universe, since it's relying on subqueries, which in MySQL aren't terribly well optimized in my experience, but it should get you your results.

You could also rework it to a different subquery to take advantage of `group_concat` like follows:

```
SELECT
    MATCH(registrants.story_title) AGAINST('bob') as rScore,
    MATCH(tags.tag) AGAINST('bob') as tScore,
    registrants.id, registrants.story_title
FROM
registrants 
LEFT JOIN (
    FROM rtags.registrant, GROUP_CONCACT(DISTINCT tags.tag SEPARATOR ',') as tags
    FROM registrants_tags AS rtags
    INNER JOIN tags on tags.id=registrants_tags.id
    GROUP BY rtags.registrant
) AS grouped_tags ON registrants.id = grouped_tags.registrant 
WHERE rScore > 0 or tScore > 0
ORDER BY (rScore + tScore) DESC
```

It would help, if in your database, you added a "grouped_tags" field to your registrant table, which could then have a fulltext index added to it - that would eliminate the need for the grouped_tags subquery. Then whenever someone updates the tags for a particular registrant, the grouped_tags field get updated with the current list of correct tags.

And if you did as I recommended about adding a grouped_tags field (that gets populated in the interface), you could replace the whole query with this, which with fulltext indexes would be pretty fast (however fulltext indexes require the use of MyISAM, which isn't exactly great).

If you did that, then this will definitely be the fastest query I've got listed here.

```
SELECT
    MATCH(story_title) AGAINST('bob') as rScore,
    MATCH(grouped_tags) AGAINST('bob') as tScore,
    id, story_title
FROM
registrants 
WHERE rScore > 0 or tScore > 0
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY (rScore + tScore) DESC
```

So there are a pile of recommendations for you for making this query happen, and which solution you go with will depend largely on the size of your data set, and how fast the query need to be. I recommend doing some benchmarking to find which one works best for you

Comment: Don't think that will work unfortunately, as I'm using to JOIN. I updated my question so you can see how a query looks like

Comment: Thanks for posting the existing query. The trick then will be to wrap the query as a sub query, then do the max on that row. I can post the updated query when I get to my computer.

Comment: Alrighty, I've given this a big update to reflect the source query.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the notification for this update, what part did you update, can you mark it please?

Comment: I basically rewrote the whole answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MATCH_SCORE_TITLE, MAX(MATCH_SCORE_TAGS), ID FROM <tablename>........GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the MAX() suggestion, however it's not working as expected, I added my sql query in my question so you can see why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT DISTINCT ID with ORDER BY MATCH_SCORE_TITLE and MATCH_SCORE_TAGS

Comment: DISTINCT was a good idea indeed, I didn't think about it. I updated the results in my question so you can see why I can't only use the first result and really need MAX() though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try at this pattern:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM registrants r1
LEFT JOIN registrants t2 ON r1.id = r2.id AND r1.MATCH_SCORE_TITLE > r2.MATCH_SCORE_TITLE
LEFT JOIN registrants_tags ON r1.registrants.id = registrants_tags.registrant 
LEFT JOIN tags ON registrants_tags.tag = tags.id
WHERE
    r2.id IS NULL AND
    (MATCH(r1.registrants.full_name) AGAINST('bob')
    OR MATCH(tags.tag) AGAINST('bob'))
ORDER BY (tscore + ascore) DESC
```

See a quick explanation of the `LEFT JOIN` trick in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131237/mysql-can-i-do-a-left-join-and-pull-only-one-row-from-the-join-table/11134161#11134161).

**Edit:** removed the unecessary GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks, however the thing is I don't need only one row, I need to group them and keep the highest score value for each. Nonetheless I still tried to make your pattern work by modifying it but never succeeded.

Comment: Oups oups oups, my bad :/ You have to remove the GROUP BY clause of course. I'm afraid I'm having some difficulties trying to understand what you really want, can you post a sample data and the result you'd like ?

Comment: Ok :D I will post an update on my question (Note that I have already clarified it, I will now add the result I would like to have)