# GROUP BY in MySQL break ORDER BY list

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT
    c.name AS category_name,
    a.name,
    a.path,
    a.extension,
    a.width,
    a.height,
    a.server
FROM categories c
JOIN news_categories nc ON nc.categories_id = c.id
JOIN news_attachments na ON nc.news_id = na.news_id
JOIN attachments a ON na.attachments_id = a.id
WHERE na.cover = 1
ORDER BY nc.news_id DESC
```

It show me a correct result

```
+---------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
| category_name | name       | path                | extension | width | height | server |
+---------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
| Игры          | c54950f283 | a6f00bcd/b25/cfaf2e | jpg       |   450 |    416 |      1 |
| Игры          | fa4249e534 | a6f00bcd/b89/cfaf2e | jpg       |   400 |    250 |      1 |
| Игры          | d7b009eeb7 | a6f00bcd/bfa/cfaf2e | jpg       |   200 |    140 |      1 |
| Игры          | 143cb7a38d | a6f00bcd/baa/cfaf2e | jpg       |   200 |    140 |      1 |
| Игры          | a70451eca7 | a6f00bcd/bc6/cfaf2e | jpg       |   200 |    140 |      1 |
| Игры          | 3ab8a0c051 | a6f00bcd/b5b/cfaf2e | jpg       |   200 |    140 |      1 |
| Игры          | 206255a07a | a6f00bcd/b98/cfaf2e | jpg       |   200 |    140 |      1 |
| Игры          | 86ef53ee1f | a6f00bcd/b93/cfaf2e | jpg       |   200 |    140 |      1 |
| Игры          | a50367f861 | a6f00bcd/b32/cfaf2e | jpg       |   200 |    140 |      1 |
| Игры          | dcfdd990c6 | a6f00bcd/b32/cfaf2e | jpg       |   200 |    140 |      1 |
| Игры          | 5a3df9f4ad | a6f00bcd/b34/cfaf2e | jpg       |   200 |    140 |      1 |
| Игры          | fb3ba0390d | a6f00bcd/b35/cfaf2e | jpg       |   200 |    140 |      1 |
| Игры          | 0e31ef118d | a6f00bcd/be5/cfaf2e | jpg       |   457 |    249 |      1 |
| Игры          | 82d41d9d62 | a6f00bcd/b97/cfaf2e | jpg       |   457 |    249 |      1 |
+---------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
```

But if we add `GROUP BY`, then it show result withot order

```
SELECT
    c.name AS category_name,
    a.name,
    a.path,
    a.extension,
    a.width,
    a.height,
    a.server
FROM categories c
JOIN news_categories nc ON nc.categories_id = c.id
JOIN news_attachments na ON nc.news_id = na.news_id
JOIN attachments a ON na.attachments_id = a.id
WHERE na.cover = 1
GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY nc.news_id DESC
```

Then the result will be

```
+---------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
| category_name | name       | path                | extension | width | height | server |
+---------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
| Игры          | 82d41d9d62 | a6f00bcd/b97/cfaf2e | jpg       |   457 |    249 |      1 |
+---------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
```

But it must be like this

```
+---------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
| category_name | name       | path                | extension | width | height | server |
+---------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
| Игры          | c54950f283 | a6f00bcd/b25/cfaf2e | jpg       |   450 |    416 |      1 |
+---------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Where it the mistake?

Comment: You are using `group by` incorrectly and every other DBMS would simply reject your query. Read this http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/ for more information.

Comment: @user2058653 what is the point of the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: I need only one result per category id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` groups your records on `c.id`. Therefore you'll only get one row for each `c.id` value.

As it happens, you have multiple rows for this value in your query, MySQL will chose and display a single row : the last one here.

For the desired ouput use `LIMIT 1`.

If you want multiple `c.id` values (category) in your resultset, you have to provide a mean of targeting the `first` row, usually a primary key.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table;

+---------------+------------+----------+
| pk            | category   | data     |
+---------------+------------+----------+
| 1             | red        | a        |
| 2             | red        | b        |
| 3             | red        | c        |
| 4             | red        | d        |
| 5             | red        | e        |
| 6             | red        | f        |
| 7             | green      | g        |
| 8             | green      | h        |
| 9             | green      | i        |
| 10            | green      | j        |
| 11            | blue       | k        |
| 12            | blue       | l        |
| 13            | blue       | m        |
| 14            | orange     | n        |
+---------------+------------+----------+
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
GROUP BY category;

+---------------+------------+----------+
| pk            | category   | data     |
+---------------+------------+----------+
| 1             | red        | a        |
| 7             | green      | g        |
| 11            | blue       | k        |
| 14            | orange     | n        |
+---------------+------------+----------+
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t
WHERE pk = (SELECT MAX(pk)
            FROM Table u
            WHERE u.category = t.category);

+---------------+------------+----------+
| pk            | category   | data     |
+---------------+------------+----------+
| 6             | red        | f        |
| 10            | green      | j        |
| 13            | blue       | m        |
| 14            | orange     | n        |
+---------------+------------+----------+
```

[Another nice way of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131237/mysql-can-i-do-a-left-join-and-pull-only-one-row-from-the-join-table/11134161#11134161)

Comment: I need only one result per category `id`, `LIMIT` will just show only one result, but category can be (Video, Games, Soft) and I need a single image for each category id with last news in this category.

Comment: Please refer to my last sentence.

Comment: Can you give an example please?